# Uploading multiple files to cocoon

Tags: file-upload, apache-cocoon

I'd love to see cocoon handle multiple files uploaded by user. My form is something like

```
<input name="file" type="file" multiple />
```

For single files (without multiple attr) it seems quite easy. Calling `cocoon.request.get("file")` in a flowscript apparently returns instance of `org.apache.cocoon.servlet.multipart.Part` so i guess I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: I'd also like know the answer. Unfortunately SO does not seem to be a good place for cocoon related questions :-(